# Redirecting method call with mixin doesn't work for LivingEntity.drop

Tags: java, mixins, minecraft-fabric

I'm currently programing a Plugin / serversided Mod for Minecraft Fabric that changes the death of a player. To be more precise: When a player dies they should keep their inventory under certain circumstances.

To accomplish this I have a class that extends `net.minecraft.entity.player.PlayerEntity` and 'mixes in' the class `net.minecraft.server.network.ServerPlayerEntity`.
Now I redirect the method call `drop()` in `onDeath(DamageSource source)` into my method were I call `this.drop()` after an if-Statement.

```
@Redirect(method = "onDeath", at = @At(value = "INVOKE",
            target = "Lnet/minecraft/server/network/ServerPlayerEntity;drop(Lnet/minecraft/entity/damage/DamageSource;)V"))
    public void redirectDrop(ServerPlayerEntity instance, DamageSource damageSource) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Drop called");
        if (!countDeath) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Kept Items");
            return;
        }
        this.drop(damageSource);
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Dropped Items");
    }
```

As you see, the `drop()` method is called when the death is counted and when it doesn't count the method is returned beforehand.

**But here comes the problem:**

When the death is not counted the inventory of the player still gets emptied but without dropping the items. But I want the player to keep their inventory and not just make them drop nothing. The weird part about this ist that in `ServerPlayerEntity.onDeath` there is this code:

```
if (!this.isSpectator()) {
    this.drop(source);
}
```

which makes the player keep his items when killed in Spectator Mode. And this works, but not my code...

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or can help me otherwise?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After some exploration of the code of Minecraft I finally have a solution for my problem:

**Firstly**

My Code works just fine: When the death is not counted the Player doesn't drop its items. The fact that the Players inventory is empty after respawning has nothing to do with the `.drop()` method.

**Secondly** 
When a Player respawns a whole new `net.minecraft.server.network.ServerPlayerEntity` is created. Therefore the newly created ServerPlayer object has an empty inventory. When dying in Spectator Mode or with KeepInventory set to true the inventory of the old ServerPlayer object gets copied to the new one.

**Finally** 
To solve my problem I injected code into the `onDeath(DamageSource source)` method of the `ServerPlayerEntity` that saves their inventory in a Map (with their UUID as key).
To restore the Players invenory I injected into the `respawnPlayer` method of `net.minecraft.server.PlayerManager` so that the inventory of the old ServerPlay object is copied to the new one.
To get the new ServerPlayer instance I redirected the `setMainArm()` method and just called it again so the behavior is the same.

My code looks like this:

```
@Redirect(method = "respawnPlayer", at = @At(value = "INVOKE",
            target = "Lnet/minecraft/server/network/ServerPlayerEntity;setMainArm(Lnet/minecraft/util/Arm;)V"))
    public void respawn(ServerPlayerEntity instance, Arm arm) {
        instance.setMainArm(arm);

        instance.getInventory().clone(INV_CACHE.get(instance.getUuid()));
        
    }
```